# Two onChange events on Materializecss Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, materialize

**Scenario:**

I'm using Materializecss autocomplete, when i select an item from the autocomplete box, an onchange event should be triggered.

**Code:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete" onchange="sendItem(this.value)">
        <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
  data: {
    "Apple": null,
    "Microsoft": null,
    "Google": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
  },
  limit: 20, 
});
  function sendItem(val) {
    console.log(val);
  }
</script>
```

**Issue:**

When i type "AP" and selects "APPLE" from the autocomplete, i need one onchange event to be triggered passing the value "APPLE" but the above program triggers onchange event twice, one passing "AP" and the next passing "APPLE". How can i trigger the latter event. Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

[here is a working jsfiddle program.](https://jsfiddle.net/varanjith/e1jmj2c3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When i type "AP" and selects "APPLE" from the autocomplete, i need one onchange event to be triggered passing the value "APPLE" but the above program triggers onchange event twice, one passing "AP" and the next passing "APPLE".

That happens because when you click/select a materialize autocomplete element two actions are performed:

- trigger change event on input field
- execute the onAutocomplete callback

But, your ***onchange inline event handler*** is executed the first time because you move on the drop down list after pressing ***AP*** and after on the autocomplete list element ***APPLE***.

*The involved materialize source code is:*

```
// Set input value
$autocomplete.on('click', 'li', function () {
  var text = $(this).text().trim();
  $input.val(text);
  $input.trigger('change');   // your issue.......
  $autocomplete.empty();
  resetCurrentElement();

  // Handle onAutocomplete callback.
  if (typeof(options.onAutocomplete) === "function") {
    options.onAutocomplete.call(this, text);
  }
});
```

In order to solve your issue you need to:

- remove the inline **onchange="sendItem(this.value)"**
- add the following callback to your autocomplete:

  onAutocomplete: function(txt) {

  ```
  sendItem(txt);
  ```

  },

In the following the snippet (or [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kj7h1ukk/)) using this approach:

```js
function sendItem(val) {
    console.log(val);
}

$(function () {
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: {
            "Apple": null,
            "Microsoft": null,
            "Google": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
        },
        onAutocomplete: function(txt) {
          sendItem(txt);
        },
        limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
                <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A different approach can be based on the [isTrigger property of event object](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js) in jQuery. Right because the second onchange event is triggered from jQuery you can test against this value:

```
function sendItem(val, e) {
    if (e.isTrigger != undefined) {
        console.log(val);
    }
}
```

That means you must add the event parameter to the inline function:

```
onchange="sendItem(this.value, event)"
```

The snippet:

```js
function sendItem(ele, e) {
    if (e.isTrigger != undefined) {
        console.log(ele.value + '   url if any: ' + $(ele).nextAll('.dropdown-content').find('img').attr('src'));
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: {
            "Apple": null,
            "Microsoft": null,
            "Google": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
        },
        limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete" onchange="sendItem(this, event)">
                <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but still i'm unable to trigger the onAutocomplete function. senditem() is not triggering with the above code. This is what i get in the debugger [![2fun.png](https://s3.postimg.org/5kd8a5oeb/2fun.png)](https://postimg.org/image/6zesyvphb/)

Comment: and thanks again. The second solution works perfect for me.

Comment: I have a related question. Is there a way to obtain the picture url from the call back? I really need it to be an employee ID not a picture. It also doesn't need to be shown.

Comment: @gaetanoM So basically what I needed was to search for the keyword Apple, but send its corresponding id to an Ajax mySQL search. Like... Search for a client name which is the key, and send the cleint id which is the value to AJAX. Hopefully I clarified it a bit more. You can extract it straight out of the returned json response imagine?

Comment: @Vini You are right. I only answer to your comment: **Is there a way to obtain the picture url from the call back?**. In order to get all the info of your interest you can use the last updated snippet in my answer.Now, in order to fetch from the server the remaing.....it's up to you. I hope I helped you. Thanks

Comment: @Vini take a look to my last snippet in the answer: **...... $(ele).nextAll('.....* and in the corresponding html ...